Why is this iframe not displaying?
I'm trying to embed a youtube video in a webpage. Seems like simple enough stuff, but for some reason the iframe isn't displaying.
I've even tried replacing the  tag altogether with one copypasted from another help thread on here that the OP seemed to have confirmed as working, but even with their working code nothing shows up on my page.
Here's the current iframe tag code I'm using:
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/riFyKUyGb4k" frameborder="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

If I view the source code for the rendered page, the iframe code is there.
But on the actual rendered page, there's nothing there. Not even an empty frameborder.
In devtools, the parent div that contains the iframe is empty — it doesn't show the iframe element as even existing at all in the rendered page.
The container div's only CSS just sets the width and height of the div, and sets the background to grey. I can see the div on the rendered page, but the div is empty.
What am I missing here?
EDIT: Adding all relevant code in case it helps
HTML:
<div id="vid_cont">

    <div id="vid_embed">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/riFyKUyGb4k" 
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

</div>

CSS:
#vid_embed {
    margin: min(3vw, 3vh) auto;
    width: min(44vw, 44vh);
    height: min(44vw, 44vh);
    background: #eee;
}


Frameborder attribute is deprecated in HTML5. Instead, you should use the style attribute with the border set to 0 or 1 as needed.style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}

This doesn't seem to be the solution to the problem — I've now removed the frameborder attribute and it's still not displaying anything. (Good tip to know though, thanks!)

Can you provide some more codes for better understanding…?

I've now added the full HTML and CSS for that section of the page.

Your code is working fine in my testing, however, you can try adding this CSS: #vid_embed {
margin: 20px auto;
width: 560px;
height: 315px;
background: #eee;
}

Also, ensure that the dimensions specified for #vid_embed are sufficient to display the iframe. The min function might be causing the container to be too small...

wow that turns out to have been it — the container div was too small, so it just didn't render the iframe

I tested out your provided code and the video is embedding fine for me, so I don't think you are missing anything. The issue could be you have other code that is conflicting with the iframe? If you haven't already first try isolating the code you provided to it's own page without any additional HTML in the body, CSS or JavaScript. If it still doesn't work, the issue could be something else entirely such as your browser's compatibility (check MDN), firewall restriction, ad-blocker, etc. Can't say for certain without seeing the rest of your code.

